# Check if element is vowel in array without regex

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a better way to check if an element is a vowel in an array?

```
foreach($alphaArray as $alpha) {
    $ascii = ord($alpha); // convert each alpha to ascii

    if($ascii == 65 || $ascii == 69 || $ascii == 73 || $ascii == 79 || $ascii == 85
        || $ascii == 97 || $ascii == 101 || $ascii == 105 || $ascii == 111 || $ascii == 117) {
        $vowelArray[] = $alpha;

    } else {
        $consonantArray[] = $alpha;
    }
}
```

Teacher does not allow regEx.

Comment: $alpha is a single letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`strtouppper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) to check if it is a vowel)

```
$vowels = array('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U');

foreach($alphaArray as $alpha) {

    if(in_array(strtoupper($alpha), $vowels)) {
        $vowelArray[] = $alpha;
    } else {
        $consonantArray[] = $alpha;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is elegant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$vowels = array('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U');
foreach($alphaArray as $alpha) {
    if(in_array($alpha, $vowels, true)) {
        $vowelArray[] = $alpha;
    } else {
        $consonantArray[] = $alpha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using strtolower and loop the array over alphabets:
strtolower will convert capital letters to small.

```
 foreach($alphaArray as $alpha) {
        $ascii = strtolower($alpha); // convert each alpha to ascii

        if($ascii == 'a' || $ascii == 'e' || $ascii == 'i' || $ascii == 'o' || $ascii == 'u') {
            $vowelArray[] = $alpha;

        } else {
            $consonantArray[] = $alpha;
        }

}
```